Error while building node-sass: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
I'm encountering an error while trying to build my project using npm install. The error message I'm getting is:
npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Desktop\my_project\client\node_modules\node-sass ... npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
Here are some details about my setup:
Node.js version: 20.17.0
npm version: 9.9.3
Python version: 3.13.0
OS: Windows 11
I've checked that Python is installed, but it seems that the distutils module is missing. I've tried reinstalling Python, ensuring that I selected the option to add Python to the PATH during the installation, but the problem persists.
What steps can I take to resolve this issue? Are there any specific dependencies I need to install for node-sass to work properly?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Starting from Python 3.12, the distutils module has been removed from the standard library. Any package that depends on it will fail to install.
You can either try installing pip install setuptools that may inlcude distutils or downgrade python to 3.11, or switch from node-sass to sass
